# Get rid of decorative search icon in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, search

There's this really annoying visual that's showing up on my taskbar that I can't figure out what it is or how to get rid of it. It displays immediately to the right of the following text

> Type here to search.

I have it circled in green in the screenshot below.

[image: Taskbar search bar--type here to search]

What is this Windows 10 searchbar functionality and how do I disable it?

(in case it matters I'm running Windows 10 Home Version 21H2)

Answer (score 2):

If you right click the taskbar, and go to the Search menu, there's the Show search highlights option you can disable. Then that preview will go away and you'll enjoy a much less distracting set of variable visuals showing up in the OS.

[image: search-highlight]